# How to include multiple mime types in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am passing the content type to a function

```
var blob = b64toBlob1(b64Data, 'application/msword');
function b64toBlob1(b64Data1, contentType, sliceSize){}
```

this mime is suitable for only .doc,to have .docx we need to include application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document ...is there any way by which i can pass both the mime types together in a single declaration

Comment: You could use an array.

Comment: Multiple MIME types should be separated by a comma such as...  'audio/mpeg,audio/mp3'